# Acces to the "burn:///" directory from the terminal?

Tags: command-line, burning, thunar

How can i acces the "burn:///" directory from the terminal on Xubuntu 14.04.

Is there an integrated option to burn the whole content to the disk without open Xfburn (it doesn't show the "burn:///" directory)?

Comment: Thanks for this hint but is there no way to find the content of this directory in the terminal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't! That's because `burn:///` is not a real directory or a real path, but is a special URI (let say a virtual directory) created by a virtual file system called Gnome Virtual File System (gvfs) and can be accesed only by a GUI file manager (like Nautilus or Thunar).

This URI - `burn:///` - is configured by `/usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-burn` file (is a binary file, so don't try and edit it).

See also: [Nautilus special URIs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/98562/37944).

Comment: Can't you access this one from gvfs-fuse?

Comment: @Gilles First time I thought that maybe is about `/run/user/<UID>/gvfs-burn` (where `<UID>` is the user id - typically 1000), but no, there is nothing when there are files in `burn:///`... Also I serched in all the system as root for a file or a link named the same as one from `burn:///`, but nothing...

Answer (score 1):

Use the gvfs- command line utilities.

Use locate to see which ones you have: `sudo updatedb` then `locate "gvfs-"`  or just type `gvfs-` + <kbd>TAB</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> to let auto-complete tell you.

- `gvfs-tree burn:` will list all the files queued for burning in a poorly parsable format (can't be piped into `gvfs-rm`).
- `gvfs-rm burn:<path to internal vfs file>` will remove that file from the queue.  A directory must be empty before you can remove it...
- `gvfs-mkdir`, `gvfs-save`, and `gvfs-copy` will help you add files.
- Use `locate "burn:"` to find where the binary file is stored, but that isn't too important since you can't modify it directly.